# Jinja2 does not recognize translation

Tags: localization, internationalization, jinja2, pelican, python-babel

I am building a site with Pelican and following [this guide](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins/blob/master/i18n_subsites/localizing_using_jinja2.rst) on localizing templates.

However, pelican output tells me: `"ERROR: Cannot find translations for language 'en' in 'translations/' with domain 'flobin'. Installing NullTranslations."` when I run the pelican command ([more here](https://gist.github.com/Flobin/79c13917a20c16dc9176).)

[This is my directory structure on the left](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qgd4ufbw29qpr1u/Screenshot%202015-12-21%2023.18.57.png?dl=0), which I think is the correct structure.

I have installed Babel.

What’s going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the conflict was with the following line in my [pelicanconf.py](https://gist.github.com/Flobin/b1fbfc8c06f20d033c34):

`I18N_GETTEXT_LOCALEDIR = 'translations/'`

Removing it completely fixed the issue.